# WPF/Silverlight XAML Stretch Text Size to Fit container?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, text, size

I've just started to play with WPF.

Is it possible to have the size of the text of a Label or TextBlock size itself to fill it's parent container?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: To clarify, are you referring to the actual point size of the typeface, or the size of the containing TextBlock/Label?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use a ViewBox to visually zoom something to fit within its container.  The other solutions here work, but they only stretch the control, not its content.  The ViewBox will stretch both.

```
<!-- Big grid, will stretch its children to fill itself -->
<Grid Width="1000" Height="1000">
 <!-- The button is stretched, but its text remains teeny tiny -->
 <Button>
  <!-- The viewbox will stretch its content 
  to fit the final size of the button -->
  <Viewbox
      Margin="4"
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
      Height="Auto">
      <!-- The textblock and its contents are 
      stretched to fill its parent -->
      <TextBlock
          Text="Bartenders" />
  </Viewbox>
 </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Will, I thought it *must* be possible, but I had visions of having to bind the font size property.

Comment: @Jmix90: Any actual numbers on performance?  It would be understandable if you had lots of these controls on a form and were resizing them often.  But performance concerns aren't until they are.

Comment: "But performance concerns aren't until they are" it's what I was pointing out .. :-D

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the parent container

Grid, DockPanel will stretch your control
StackPanel, WrapPanel will leave it to the control to size itself..

Answer (score 1):

Set HorizonalAlignment/VerticalAlignment to "stretch".

Answer (score 0):

Use DockPanel as parent container

```
<DockPanel>
  <TextBlock />
</DockPanel>
```